# Configure Swagger UI (Jersey REST API with Maven/Tomcat)

Tags: java, rest, maven, swagger, swagger-ui

I have found similar Stack Overflow posts for configuring Swagger + SwaggerUI + Jersey, but almost all of these use Spring and I have not been able to find a solution for what I am trying to do.

I have Swagger + Jersey working, and have copied the `swagger-ui/dist` folder from: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui to my `webapp` directory, and have edited `swagger-ui/dist/index.html` file to point to my `swagger.json` output. I can properly access Swagger UI at `http://localhost:{port}/{base-path}/dist/index.html`

However, I do not want to have to copy the pre-build `dist` files to my webapp directory every time I need to fetch updates. I would like to automate this with Maven (which I am new to as well as Jersey/Swagger), and found this dependency online: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/swagger-ui/2.0.12

However, I do not understand how to configure the path from my webserver to this webjar dependency.

To recap, I have Swagger UI working on my local machine, but only by manually copying the pre-build files to my `webapp` directory and would like some way to automate this (I have found solutions using Spring, but I am not using this).

Comment: I, too, am struggling with how to use the swagger-ui webjar from within my Jersey web service project.  Have you figured this out?